# Remove single-letter words (and a leading or trailing space) from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, cpu-word

I have a string like: `Bruce A Johnson`

I want it to be `Bruce Johnson`.

How do I remove the single `A` from the string with PHP? (all 'words' of only 1 character need to be removed)

Comment: `all 'words' of only 1 character need to be removed` This is not a specification. Its undefined as a phrase and without definition. It only means something to you the interpreter of a name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this:

```
preg_replace('/\b\w\b\s?/', '', $string);
```

This says remove any single word character that has a word boundary on either side and optionally a trailing space.

Thus `b test a test foo c` will yield `test test foo`.

If you might have some trailing punctuation (like `Bruce A. Johnson`) you can get rid of the punctuation with this expression:

```
preg_replace('/\b\w\b(\s|.\s)?/', '', $string);
// 'b test a, test foo c' -> 'test test foo'
```

Comment: Works great. This is really helpful when creating a clean URL string for a post slug.

Comment: In addition to letters, this appears to also remove numbers. Not sure if that is intentional or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use explode() to split up the three words, remove the middle element of the returned array, and then implode() to rejoin the string.

Comment: Thanx, but I have a feeling this needs to be done with a regular expression... Only problem is I'm not good at regexes :)

Comment: @Dylan Regex certainly isn't required for this, as there are several ways to do it. Regex might yield the most concise code, but it also might take greater execution time compared to regex-less methods. These are among the reasons you'd consider one way over another.

Comment: Creating an array of words, then looping to prune elements by string length, then re-imploding is definitely not something that I would entertain in a professional project (but I am very comfortable with regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

`/\b\w\b\s?` will not remove the lingering space on a string like `Maggie Q`.

for a robust pattern to remove either the leading or trailing space, but never both, use a "conditional expression" based on an optional capture group.

Effectively, if the first capture group match is true, then do not match anything after the letter (this is why there isn't anything written between `(1)` and `|`).  If the first capture group match is false, then optionally match a trailing space (it might not exist).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YOu5H))

```
$array = [
    'Bruce A Johnson',
    'Maggie Q',
    'L B Johnson',
    'X',
    'F Mercury',
    'R O C K in the U S A'
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('/( )?\b\w\b(?(1)| ?)/', '', $array)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Bruce Johnson',
  1 => 'Maggie',
  2 => 'Johnson',
  3 => '',
  4 => 'Mercury',
  5 => 'in the',
)
```

For anyone seeking a pattern which also caters to single letters that have optional trailing dots, then I recommend [`/( )?\b\w\b\.?(?(1)| ?)/`](https://3v4l.org/Yql1u) over `/\b\w\b(\s|.\s)?/` because that `.` in Mark Elliots's pattern is not escaped, and again, better handling of leading spaces.